# How to render the user profile avatar image into the wagtail template?

Tags: django-templates, wagtail

I am creating a blog site using the Wagtail CMS. I would like to display the Author avatar image whenever a new post is published. I am trying to render the image from this `/admin/account/change_avatar/` location. I can see the image uploaded here is under the `wagtailusers_userprofile -> col name: avatar` table, but not sure how to render it in the template.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This image isn't a typical Wagtail Image (one that comes from `wagtailimages.Image`), this looks like a regular `models.ImageField`.

Here's what's in the UserProfile model for the avatar:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='wagtail_userprofile'
    )

    avatar = models.ImageField(
        verbose_name=_('profile picture'),
        upload_to=upload_avatar_to,
        blank=True,
    )
```

Because this is a regular image field, you can get the url by appending `.url` in your template.

Here's some example template code:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
  {% if request.user.wagtail_userprofile.avatar %}
    <img src="{{ request.user.wagtail_userprofile.avatar.url }}" alt="{{ request.user.get_full_name }}">
  {% else %}
    {# No image #}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

The above code will check to see if the user is authenticated in the template. If you don't need it, ditch it.

THen there's the `if` statement to checks of the `request.user.wagtail_userprofile.avatar` exists. The `wagtail_userprofile` comes from the `user` field on the `UserProfile` model. It's using a `related_name`, so we use that in the template.

I also sprinkled in a `{{ request.user.get_full_name }}` for the alt tag, because the image alt should probably be the users name in this case, rather than the file name.

If you need the height or width, those are both available through the `{{ request.user.wagtail_userprofile.avatar.height }}` and `{{ request.user.wagtail_userprofile.avatar.width }}`.

Comment: Thank you @Kalob Taulien for the solution. By the way, I learned wagtail by watching all your tutorials from the [Coding For Everybody](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_yA25ZmNkA&list=PLMQHMcNi6ocsS8Bfnuy_IDgJ4bHRRrvub) Youtube channel.

Comment: How would this look when a gravatar is used? I found (from wagtail.users.utils import get_gravatar_url)