# Wagtail profile avatar into ImageRenditionField serializer

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, wagtail

I want to serialize the profile avatar from Wagtail admin with ImageRenditionField.
Basing on the answer from the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952994/how-to-render-the-user-profile-avatar-image-into-the-wagtail-template) I tried this:

```
# models.py
class User(AbstractUser):

    def get_avatar(self):
        return self.wagtail_userprofile.avatar


# serializers.py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    avatar = ImageRenditionField('width-190', source='get_avatar')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'avatar']
```

I got this:

```
Django Version: 3.1.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'get_rendition'
```

How do I throw user avatar into ImageRenditionField?

Comment: I checked source code of the userprofile,  it is not inherited from the `AbstractImage` model, which means you won't have `get_rendition` available for this image. you can resize in your serializermethod though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `avatar` field is a regular Django `ImageField`. It does not have `get_rendition`, it does not have any Wagtail rendition logic.

Take a look at [wagtail.users.models.UserProfile.avatar](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/cf38b2457dba521d029d3a6e5024a7d0c3f5faf6/wagtail/users/models.py#L56-L60)

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ...

    avatar = models.ImageField(
        verbose_name=_('profile picture'),
        upload_to=upload_avatar_to,
        blank=True,
    )
```

and [wagtail.images.models.AbstractImage.file](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/cf38b2457dba521d029d3a6e5024a7d0c3f5faf6/wagtail/images/models.py#L63-L376) (this is the base class of Wagtail `Image`).

```
class AbstractImage(CollectionMember, index.Indexed, models.Model):
    ...
    file = models.ImageField(
        verbose_name=_('file'), upload_to=get_upload_to, width_field='width', height_field='height'
    )
```

Notice that `avatar` field is a regular Django `ImageField`. The  Wagtail image is a *model* that stores additional image information and handles filters, focal points and renditions.

You can NOT use the Wagtail renditions in combination with avatar field, because avatar is a Django ImageField and not a Wagtail Image.

There are [various thumbnail packages](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/thumbnails/) that provide thumbnail/scale functionality for Django ImageFields. Don't adjust the `UserProfile.avatar` field itself (customising Wagtail). Search for packages that play nice with plain ImageFields.

[This question and answer might interest you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834664/django-rest-framework-with-easy-thumbnails).

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = "__all__"
    avatar = serializers.SerializerMethodField("get_avatar_display")
    def get_avatar_display(self,info):
        return info.wagtail_userprofile.avatar.url
```

Comment: Do you mean getting the url of the avatar? Yes that works. But what I want is put the avatar into ImageRenditionField and be able to crop or resize the avatar.

Comment: you can install django-resized